# using multiple video inputs simultaniously for a hangout app

Tags: video, google-hangouts

I am interested in developing a simple app for Google hangouts that allows a user to use his  normal built in webcam to film his face, while a secondary usb-connected webcam films something else simultaniously which is displayed in the app-screen.
Is it possible to do this with the hangouts api?

Answer (score 0):

Google+ Hangouts do support multiple instances of your webcam feed within the application. However the camera selection is a global configuration so you would not be able to do what you are wishing for. Also the hangouts plugin does not allow opening more than one hangout from one computer. Hence in order to accomplish multiple feeds from two webcams, you can try obviously using two computers (and login with two different ids) or create a virtual machine and join as a different user inside the VM.

Comment: Murukesh's third sentence here isn't true anymore. Google Hangouts apparently have been able to support different devices with the same Google+ login for a while:  http://gizmodo.com/google-hangouts-has-a-weird-fun-multi-cam-trick-508504684